# Hitting enter on Auto Complete Extended text box causes post back

Tags: asp.net-ajax

In my ASPX page I have an Ajax Control toolkit provided 'Auto Complete extended text box' (tried having explicitly stating `AutoPostBack="false"`).
Auto Complete data is fetching data from the Web Service.
And it’s working fine.

But when focus is set in text box and I hit enter it causes a post back.
Other than this 'Auto Complete Extender' and 'Extended Text Box' there is no control and not a single line of code which may enforce this.

I tried it in IE7 and IE8 both.

And the strangest thing I found is; when I just add another textbox control in my test page the problem mentioned above disappears.

Thanks in Advance
Rajdip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug/oddity of IE - a single text box causes a postback. This is especially annoying when you have a text box and a search buttun, and clicking <kbd>enter</kbd> causes a dummy postback (not a button click).
As you've discovered, a good solution is to add another text box, ***even an hidden text box*** (`display:none`), and the postback goes away.